# Model with a tuple as an primary key

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table who's PK is the tuple: (user_id, sotry_id).

how do i define that in Cakephp?

thank,
Boris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe cakephp doesn't support composite primary keys as standard:

[CakePHP's Multiple Primary Key Problem](http://alexanderkohout.de/blog/cakephps-multiple-primary-key-problem/)

Although that page does link to a suggested work-around using an override of `exists` (but I must admit I haven't tried it!).

Comment: Yes, just use "id". It's not that big of a deal or overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Never used cakephp, but the answer should be simple:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

```
    class Example extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'example_id'; // example_id is the field name in the database
}
```